# Powershell - Testing WebServices with XML

Tags: xml, web-services, powershell

I'm just trying to send a XML parameter to a web service and getting an error...
First, Is it possible ??

Look my script :

```
#Web Service
$Uri = "http://xxxx.svc?WSDL"

#Path Xml
$XmlPath = "C:\xxxx\test2.xml"

#Objects
$Xml = New-Object "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1ices_MarketingService_svc_WSDL.GetTopOrderedProductsRequest"
$WebService = New-Object "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1ices_MarketingService_svc_WSDL.GetTopOrderedProductsRequest"
$Response = New-Object "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1ices_MarketingService_svc_WSDL.GetTopOrderedProductsRequest"

#Xml parameters
$Xml = [xml](get-content $XmlPath)

#Web Service
$WebService = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $Uri

$Response = $WebService.GetTopOrderedProducts($Xml)

$Response
```

I have this error :

> Cannot convert argument "request", with value:
>   "System.Xml.XmlDocument", for "GetTopOrderedProducts" to type 
>   "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy37ices_MarketingService_svc_WSDL.GetTopOrderedProductsRequest":
>   "Cannot convert the  "System.Xml.XmlDocument" value of type
>   "System.Xml.XmlDocument" to type 
>   "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy37ices_MarketingService_svc_WSDL.GetTopOrderedProductsRequest"."
>   At D:\Exploit\WebServices\test.ps1:18 char:1
>   + $Response = $WebService.GetTopOrderedProducts($Xml)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

If anyone can help me.. Thank you !